# performSegue view not in window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

I'm trying to perform a segue to another view controller with this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    placemarkIndex = indexPath.row
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: K.Segues.cityViewController, sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == K.Segues.cityViewController {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! CityViewController
        if let index = placemarkIndex, let city = cities?[index] {
            destinationVC.location = city
        }
    }
}
```

the segue works when I search the table view and select the row while searching, however, it returns the following error when clicking on a row without searching action enabled:

*Warning: Attempt to present <Simple_Forecast.CityViewController: 0x7fadc9893a00> on <Simple_Forecast.SearchViewController: 0x7fadcc12f390> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!*

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Is perform segue to cityVC done anywhere else in your code?

Comment: No, only there.

Comment: That warning usually occurs when the view is not attached to the window. Since I don't know how the other parts of the code looks like Im taking a guess here. The search VC might not be presented as the search action is not enabled. So performing from search VC to city VC throws that warning.